# Android SharedPreferences error: SharedPreferences.Editor cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android

I will use SharedPreferences in my code, but I have a problem. It gives below error.

```
- SharedPreferences.Editor cannot be resolved to a type
- The method edit() is undefined for the type SharedPreferences
```

Code:

```
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

import android.app.backup.SharedPreferencesBackupHelper;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

private SharedPreferences preferences;

preferences = (SharedPreferences) getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
```

Even if I use `Editor editor = preferences.edit();`, it gives same error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)`

```
preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```